# Slow Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have following query(this is just part of it, but problematic is that last bit):

```
 query = context.TR.Where(tr => tr.REF == 1).Select(db2 => new Stops
                                        {
                                            Track = db2.TRACK,
                                            Distance = db2.DISTANCE,
                                            Delta = db2.DELTA,
                                            IsValid = db2.IS_VALID,
                                            Pos = db2.POS,
                                            RefAL = db2.REFAL,
                                            Ref = db2.REF,
                                            Stop = context.PhysicalStops.Where(ps => ps.Id == db2.REFAL)
                                                .Select(db3 => new PhysicalStop
                                                {
                                                    Id = db3.Id,
                                                    Code = db3.Code,
                                                    Label = db3.Label,
                                                    Lattitude = db3.Lattitude,
                                                    Longitude = db3.Longitude,
                                                    ComId = db3.ComId,
                                                    VersId = db3.VersId,
                                                    FrId = db3.FrId
                                                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                                            Code = context.FS.Where(db4 => db4.Id == db4.PhysicalStops.Where(ps => ps.Id == db2.REFAL).FirstOrDefault().StopId)
                                                .Select(db4 => context.ZN.Where(db5 => db5.Id == db4.ZoneId).Select(db6 => (short)db6.Code)).FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault()
                                        });
```

Following part is extremly slow, commenting it out is making query execute in few seconds,but with this part of code it takes few minutes:

```
 Code = context.FS.Where(db4 => db4.Id == db4.PhysicalStops.Where(ps => ps.Id == db2.REFAL).FirstOrDefault().StopId)
                                                    .Select(db4 => context.ZN.Where(db5 => db5.Id == db4.ZoneId).Select(db6 => (short)db6.Code)).FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault()
```

Is there some reason why this part is so slow? Could it be speed up? Can't figure this one out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a complex question. Depends on many things. 
EF version, models configuration. You also can you SSMS profiler to get raw SQL.
It can also be the in-memory execution (depends on EF version).

Comment: If using EF Core use [ToQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0) to generate a string representation of the query.

Comment: Also consider [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging) for your case, to Visual Studio's output window. This is for EF Core 5 and higher.

Comment: on first look, you use many subqueries which can be slow. As wrote @Sergey many other thing can depend on your query.

Comment: This seems odd to have two FirstOrDefault -> .FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault(). And why are you casting db6.Code?